# Using sed to remove leading and trailing white spaces

Tags: macos, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
   2 1 word
  78 3 other words
   2 some other words here
  54 bla bla
```

I'd like to remove whitespaces and put a comma between values and rest. the output should look like

```
2,1 word
78,3 other words
2,some other words here
54,bla bla
```

The command

```
sed -e 's/\s*([0-9])+\s.+/&/'
```

does not change anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick?

```
sed -Ee 's/^[[:space:]]+([0-9]+)[[:space:]]+/\1,/' bob 
2,1 word
78,3 other words
2,some other words here
54,bla bla
```

Comment: illegal option r (under OSX)

Comment: Well, clean up you tags, then :) ... you tagged it as Linux Bash  Or install a decent sed using homebrew ;}

Comment: ++; simply use `-E` instead of `-r`, and it'll work on OSX (incidentally, GNU `sed` supports `-E` too, even though the man page doesn't say so).

Comment: @mklement0 : thanks for the -E reference; I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will work with any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//; s/[[:space:]]*$//; s/[[:space:]]/,/' file
2,1 word
78,3 other words
2,some other words here
54,bla bla
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
sed -e 's/(\d) (\d)(*)/\1,\2\3' infile.txt
```

Comment: sed: 1: "s/(\d) (\d)(*)/\1,\2\3
": \1 not defined in the RE

Comment: @Arif: Did you actually try that ? :)